# React useHistory, Object is of type 'unknown'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I got error **Object is of type 'unknown'** when using react hook useHisotry, here is the details, thanks in advance for your help!

Node version: v12.14.1

React version: 17.0.1

react-router-dom version: 16.9.8

@types of react-router-dome version: ^5.1.6

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const history = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {
    if (history.location.state) {
      const taskId: any = history.location.state.taskId
      getItemList(taskId)
    }
  }, [])
```

// Error message

```
  Object is of type 'unknown'.  TS2571

    252 |   useEffect(() => {
    253 |     if (history.location.state) {
  > 254 |       const taskId: any = history.location.state.taskId
        |                           ^
    257 |     }
```

Comment: Why do you declare constant like this ``const taskId: any = history.location.state.taskId``?

Comment: Please try only like this ``const taskId=history.location.taskId``

Comment: @EtsukoSusui are you sure? do you know what's in location?

Comment: Are you using history outside of component implementation?

Comment: @lissettdm, no, I use it inside a function component.

Comment: You need to wrap the component with hoc WIthRouter from "react-router-dom" or pass it to a Route directly, could you show how you have wrapper the component in App.js and how you have handled routing

Comment: @GouthamJ.M thank, useHistory is Hook, it doesn't need HOC.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to do something similar to get the previous URL from which the current component has been navigated to.

Here is what I did:

In the component where you push the url in the history object:

```
 history.push(`/overview`, {
      from: '/map',
    } as { from: string });
```

Now, in the component where you want to use the history object:

```
const history = useHistory();
const state = history.location.state as { from: string }

console.log(state.from); // this will give you the value from the state
```

In your case, replace "from" with "taskId".

I hope that helps. Since you define what properties to include in the location state, it is safe to define a type for it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the type of the state object like this:

```
const history = useHistory<{ taskId: string }>();
const taskId = history.location.state.taskId
```

Answer (score -1):

You should consider get history from props instead. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history/history-is-mutable
See the example below.

```
export default function ExampleComponent(props: any) {

const { taskId } = props.history.location.state;

 console.log(taskId);

}
```

if you don't want to use props consider using `useLocation` hook . The useLocation hook returns the location object that represents the current URL. You can think about it like a useState that returns a new location whenever the URL changes. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation

```
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
export default function ExampleComponent(props: any) {
 let location = useLocation();
const { taskId } = location.state;

  console.log(taskId);

}
```

Comment: They are trying to use `useHistory`, so history wouldn't be coming from props.

Comment: @Xymostech history is mutable
The history object is mutable. Therefore it is recommended to access the location from the render props of <Route>, not from history.location. This ensures your assumptions about React are correct in lifecycle hooks see https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history/history-is-mutable